# JSON parsing to table through KNIME

Tags: json, knime

I  am trying to parse JSON file through KNIME, now in output we are getting 4 rows which is correct but in these 4 rows (corresponding to number of `PsnameId` parameter in the input JSON).

Now we need to have 10 new columns for `Flgs.cd(Flgs.cd1,Flgscd2....Flgs.cd10)` and `Flgs.des(Flgs.des1,Flgs.des2....Flgs.des10)` which should get data from parameters `Flgs.cd` and `Flgs.des`.

`Row 1` should have data in `Flgs.cd1` as `A1`, `Flgs.Cd2` as `A2`, `Flgs.cd3` as `null`...`Flgs.cd10` as `null` (as there are two elements under `Flgs` parameter) and in `Flgs.des1` as first system, `Flgs.des2` as second system...`Flgs.des10` as `null`)

`Row 2` should have data in `Flgs.cd1` as `B1`, `Flgs.cd2` as `B2`, `Flgs.cd3` as `B3`...`Flgs.cd10` as `null` (as there are three elements under `Flgs` parameter) and `Flgs.des1` as first system, `Flgs.des2` as second system, `Flgs.des3` as third system...`Flgs.des10` as `null`)

`Row 3` should have data in `Flgs.cd1` as `null`, `Flgs.cd2` as `null`, `Flgs.cd3` as `null`...`Flgs.cd10` as `null` (as there are no elements under `Flgs` parameter) and `Flgs.des1` as `null`, `Flgs.des2` as `null`...`Flgs.des10` as `null`)

`Row 4` should have data in `Flgs.cd1` as `null`, `Flgs.cd2` as `null`, `Flgs.cd3` as `null`...`Flgs.cd10` as `null` (as there are no elements under `Flgs` parameter) and `Flgs.des1` as `null`, `Flgs.des2` as `null`...`Flgs.des10` as `null`)

I have tried using *Ungroup* for `Flgs` parameter as Node 15  but it  is creating  new rows equal to the number of `Flgs` elements present under each `PsnameId`, which is not the expected output. Can you please let me know if we can

JSON input:

```
{
"mod": "8976",
"machine": {
    "Comments": [],
    "machineis": false,
    "Person": {
        "Address": null,
        "Gender": "Female",
        "LastName": "juhi",
        "Location": null,
        "MiddleName": null
    },
    "Specials": [{
        "Comments": [],
        "DDateTime": "2018-11-14T09:40:37",
        "Contain": [{
            "Comments": null,
            "CID": "256521",
            "Instance": [{
                "ADateTime": null,
                "ObsertsRIDs": ["11", "12"],
                "RID": "11",
                "Type": null
            }, {
                "ADateTime": null,
                "ObsertsRIDs": ["13", "14"],
                "RID": "12",
                "Type": null
            }],
            "Obserts": [{
                "PsnameId": "123-7",
                "PsName": "gdsa DF",
                "RstID": "11",
                "Result": {
                    "Comments": [],
                    "CompletedDateTime": null,
                    "RsltID": "11"
                },
                "Flgs": [
                    {
                        "Cd": "A1",
                        "Des": "first system",
                        "Type": "null"
                    },
                    {
                        "Cd": "A2",
                        "Des": "second system",
                        "Type": "null"
                    }
                ],
                "Type": null,
                "Version": 0
            }, {
                "PsnameId": "897-1",
                "PsName": "sads RT",
                "RstID": "12",
                "Result": {
                    "Comments": [],
                    "CompletedDateTime": null,
                    "RsltID": "12"
                },
                "Flgs": [
                    {
                        "Cd": "B1",
                        "Des": "first system",
                        "Type": "null"
                    },
                    {
                        "Cd": "B2",
                        "Des": "second system",
                        "Type": "null"
                    },
                    {
                        "Cd": "B3",
                        "Des": "third system",
                        "Type": "null"
                    }
                ],
                "Type": null,
                "Version": 0
            },  {
                "PsnameId": "897-1",
                "PsName": "sads RT",
                "RstID": "13",
                "Result": {
                    "Comments": [],
                    "CompletedDateTime": null,
                    "RsltID": "13"
                },
                "Flgs": [],
                "Type": null,
                "Version": 0
            },{
                "PsnameId": "891-1",
                "PsName": "rgst LT",
                "RstID": "14",
                "Result": {
                    "Comments": [],
                    "CompletedDateTime": null,
                    "RsltID": "14"
                },
                "Flgs": [],
                "Type": null,
                "Version": 0
            }],
            "CAct": null,
            "Type": null,
            "Version": 0
        }],
        "Type": null,
        "Version": 0
    }],
    "Cals": null,
    "Pals": null,
    "Type": null,
    "Version": 0
}
}
```

[image: KNIME workflow picture]

Output table picture:
[image: Output table picture]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for [`Ungroup`](https://hub.knime.com/knime/extensions/org.knime.features.base/latest/org.knime.base.node.preproc.ungroup.UngroupNodeFactory) and [`Pivoting`](https://hub.knime.com/knime/extensions/org.knime.features.base/latest/org.knime.base.node.preproc.pivot.Pivot2NodeFactory). Pivoting will needs some configuration, but it should work with some experimenting, do not get afraid of the `Ungroup` result rows.